# Surah Mulk verse 5, surah al-baqarah verse 29

Tags: quran, tafseer, science

I've read a lot about Surah Mulk verse 5 on the internet, but it's not really making sense to me, The verse says

> "And indeed We have adorned the nearest heaven with lamps, and We have made such lamps (as) missiles to drive away the Shayatin, and have prepared for them the torment of the blazing Fire.)."

Tafseer ibn Kathir says

> "This refers to the stars which have been placed in the heavens, some moving and some stationary. In Allah's statement, The pronoun `them' in His statement, "and We have made them'' is the same type of statement as the stars being referred to as lamps. This does not mean that they are actually missiles, because the stars in the sky are not thrown. Rather, it is the meteors beneath them that are thrown and they are taken from the stars."

First of all, what is this "nearest heaven"?, In surah baqarah verse 29, it says Allah first created earth then created the 7 heavens,
29.

> " It is He who created for you everything on earth, then turned to the heaven, and made them seven heavens. And He is aware of all things"

so what region is the nearest heaven, and more generally 7 heavens? Earth's atmosphere or outer space? The "lamps" are certainly stars, and stars exist in outer space, which existed before the formation of earth, so what do you make of that?
Moreover the stars don't throw anything toward us, even if they did, the closest star to us is 4.25 light-years away, it would take the "missiles" millions of years to reach us, and if the "missiles" here are astroids or meteorites or comets, then we know that they're not being thrown at devils, it happens bcz of gravity, sun's and planetary gravity not other star's gravity.

what is being thrown at shyatin?

And why does surah Mulk verse 5 talks about stars?

What are the 7 heavens?
Thank you very much:

Comment: Please stick to one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading [37:6-10](https://quran.com/as-saffat).

**Allah tells us that He has adorned the lowest heaven with the heavenly bodies for those among the people of the earth who look at it.

The star-like lamps hit the devils that try to hear the highest assembly ˹of angels˺. In the assembly Allah gives commandment to Angels all standing in rows. The Devils are pelted from every side and are driven away but some that stealthily gather some news they instantly are burned. *(I think the shooting stars we see are the devils being pelted)*.**

*We are not hit by the stars because we are not devils nor we are able to hear the highest assembly.*

I think there is no *in-detail information* of the seven heavens. A person may call the outer space the nearest heaven because that is where the stars are.

***Your Question is very jumbled up, not easy to read and there are
multiple questions in it which aren't in an orderly fashion. You state
your knowledge then a question, again your knowledge than a question. I tried to fix it but the edit was rejected by you.***

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution, but I would humbly say that I wrote the question in this way to show the discrepancy or apparent discrepancy in the astronomical model given in quran, if the Qur'an has a working astronomical model, these questions are very easy to answer, I rejected the edit bcz it left out some important details.

Comment: @NaveedAli, there are similar question like these asked, do take a look at them